# Cannot subscript a value of type [(String, Int)] with an index of type (String, Int) Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, tuples

I am learning iOS development, and have recently come across an issue when attempting to manipulate an array of tuples.

I get the following error message:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[(String, Int)]' with an index of type '(String, Int)'

The code generating it is as follows:

```
justStrings.append(filteredRestraunts[i2].0)
```

The function as a whole is this:

```
    func filterBySliderValue () -> [String] {
    var filteredRestraunts: [(String, Int)]
    for var i = 0; i < restraunts.count; i++ {
        if restraunts[i].1 > Int(starSlider.value) {
            filteredRestraunts.append(restraunts[i])
        }
        else {filteredRestraunts.append(("", 1))}
    }
    var justStrings: [String]
    var i2 = 0
    for i2 in filteredRestraunts {
        justStrings.append(filteredRestraunts[i2].0)
    }
    return justStrings
}
```

This is the array restraunts:

```
var restraunts: [(String, Int)] = [("Dallas BBQ", 3), ("Chicken Express", 4), ("Starbucks", 5)]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
for i2 in filteredRestraunts {
    justStrings.append(filteredRestraunts[i2].0)
}
```

`i2` is not an index, but iterates over the array *elements*, i.e.
it is a `(String, Int)` tuple. What you probably meant is

```
for i2 in filteredRestraunts {
    justStrings.append(i2.0)
}
```

*Additional remarks:*

- The variable

  ```
  var i2 = 0
  ```

  is not used at all, `i2` in the for-loop is a new variable whose scope is
  restricted to the loop.
- The variables `filteredRestraunts` and `justStrings`
  are not initialized, so this should cause additional compiler errors.
- Both loops can be replaced by a more functional approach using 
  `filter` and `map`:

  ```
  let filteredRestraunts = restraunts.filter { $0.1 > Int(starSlider.value) }
  let justStrings = filteredRestraunts.map { $0.0 }
  ```

  Which of course could be combined to

  ```
  let justStrings = restraunts.filter { $0.1 > Int(starSlider.value) }.map { $0.0 }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed the scope warning, and initialized (and immediately emptied) the arrays, and now the application works. I have seen the use of the map and filter functions before, but still have no idea how they work (or even how to use them.) Again, thanks for the help, I've had this bug all week.